# Using Polymorphism in Spring Boot services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, polymorphism

In my Spring Boot app, I am thinking of using an approach as the following interface and service implementations:

***PDFService:***

```
public interface PDFService {
    String createPdf(UUID uuid);
}
```

***BrandPDFService:***

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BrandPDFService implements PDFService {
    
    private final BrandService brandService;

    @Override
    public String createPdf(UUID uuid) {
        Brand brand = brandService.findByUuid(uuid);

        // ... code omitted for brevity

        return generateHtml(brand);
    }
}
```

***ProductPDFService:***

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductPDFService implements PDFService {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @Override
    public String createPdf(UUID uuid) {
        Product product = productService.findByUuid(uuid);

        // ... code omitted for brevity

        return generateHtml(product);
    }
}
```

For using these services:

```
// brand way
PDFService pdfService = new BrandService();
pdfService.createPdf(uuid);


// product way
PDFService pdfService = new ProductService();
pdfService.createPdf(uuid);
```

So, I think I need to use generic and pass it to PDFService and then their implementations, but I am not sure how to make it properly (using generic or passing via constructor). So, in order to use `createPdf` efficiently without repeating code (I know I can also use Template Pattern method, but I just wanted to know polymorphism side) how should I apply polymorphism to these Spring Boot Services properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Template Method Pattern with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062796/using-template-method-pattern-with-spring-boot)

Comment: No need to have a `PDFService` in the first place if you are not using a `PDFService` anywhere. There is not much to simplify here since there is little to no code duplication,

Answer (score 1):

Since `BrandPDFService` and `ProductPDFService` are Spring beans (because you annotated them with the `@Service` annotation), you should not be instantiating them yourself by using `new`. Instead, you should let Spring autowire them into the class where you are using them.

Because they are both implementations of interface `PDFService`, when you autowire them, you need to have something to let Spring distinguish them. Otherwise, if the field you are autowiring them in is of type `PDFService`, Spring won't know which implementation of the interface to autowire. You can give the beans names and use the `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Service("brandPDFService")
public class BrandPDFService implements PDFService { ... }

@Service("productPDFService")
public class ProductPDFService implements PDFService { ... }

// Example controller where you autowire them
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("brandPDFService")
    private PDFService brandPDFService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("productPDFService")
    private PDFService productPDFService;

    // ...
}
```

> So, I think I need to use generic and pass it to PDFService and then their implementations

I don't know why you think you need to use generics; this doesn't have anything to do with generics.